# relativeLayout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.sample_drawable)); is crashing the app on API 19

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-relativelayout

I have a simple layout file for which I want to use a drawable in the background of main container

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mlv_balance_detail_container"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    **android:background="@drawable/sample_drawable"** //this was causing crash in 4.4.2 API 19
    android:padding="@dimen/dimen_16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_policy_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:letterSpacing="0.04"
        tools:text="text"
        android:textColor="#1d252d"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_total_balance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_policy_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:letterSpacing="0.04"
        tools:text="some text"
        android:textColor="#1d252d"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Then I tried setting the background from code using

```
container.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.sample_drawable));
```

It is still crashing, can anyone help me out here?
Thanks,

Comment: You have sample_drawable in your drawables?

Comment: `sample_drawable` is vector. show error log

Comment: Yes, it is a vector(xml) and is placed in drawable folder

Comment: can you post full crash report?

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution for this problem, although I would still look for a better answer but for the time being, I am using an ImageView inside a FrameLayout and setting app:srcCompat property of Imageview which is backward compatible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/sample_drawable" />

        </FrameLayout>

    //rest of my layout as it is

    </RelativeLayout>
```